# Viewing Google Calendar through WinForm

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, google-calendar-api

I'm having difficulty viewing Google Calendar through WinForms. I have my code below:

```
public GoogleCalendar()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    gcalendar = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
    gcalendar.Navigate("https://www.google.com/calendar/");

    gcalendar.Show();
    gcalendar.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
}
```

I'm also getting a JavaScript error alert, which I'm trying to suppress. I'm unable to view Google Calendar in the WinForms window. I was able to get Google Calendar to be visible by using WPF, but I still get the JavaScript error.

Comment: Don't suppress the errors, at least temporarily. Aside from the javascript error what error(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

To display a useful calendar via the URL `https://www.google.com/calendar/` requires the browser you're using to have a Google session (in cookies).

This browser control you're creating in your winforms app almost surely doesn't have such a session. You will need the calendar's public URL to make this work. Go to the calendar UI. Click on the little `v` next to the calendar's name, choose Calendar Settings, and get the URL. Use that in your form.